# Correct method to download VHD from Azure

Tags: azure

I've been attempting to download the VHD for my stopped VM from Azure but run into disconnects and my download never completes.

Is there a preferred/correct method to download VHD's from Azure?

Update: I've tried to use 'Azure Storage Explorer', on a 29GB VHD, about 3GB downloaded and I receive an error: "Unable to read data from the transport connection. The connection was closed."

I work remotely on a residential broadband connection, so if someone with a much faster connecion could confirm downloading large VHD's works, that would help nail this issue down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried AzureStorageExplorer? Assuming you want to do these manually, rather than from code, it seems to work pretty well for me although I've not used it to download VHDs.

http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yes, I've tried that and edited my question above with details.

Comment: I've accepted this answer as I suspect it is valid for all cases except slow connections (such as mine).

Comment: Did it actually work for you?  I keep getting "Failed To Download" "The server is busy."